# How to populate the check box values declared inside ajax response function to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In this snippet I'm getting `on` as the result but if you check in code I'm asking it to store the selected `user_email` as values, but its not happening.

```js
$("#goBtn").on("click",function(){

  //assume I have the response data as follows:
  var response = {
    data:[
        {
          user_name: "zyx",
          user_email: "zyx.com",
          user_contact: "5555",
          state: "tn",
          city: "chennai",
          user_license: ""
        },
        {
          user_name: "abx",
          user_email: "abx.com",
          user_contact: "45555",
          state: "tn",
          city: "mumbai",
          user_license: ""
        }
      ]
  };

  for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
  
$("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> <input type='checkbox', value: response.data[i].user_email>"+response.data[i].user_name+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_contact+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_license+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_email+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].state+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].city);
  }
});

//to process selected users: 
 $('#clickme').on('click', function(){
  var selected = $('input:checked');
   var emails = [];
   selected.each(function(){
    //alert(element);
    emails.push($(this).val());
   });
   
   $('#check-emails').html(emails);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="goBtn">Go</button>
<table id="table" border=1>
  <tr>
   <th> Name </th>
   <th> contact </th>
   <th> license </th>
   <th> email </th>
   <th> state </th>
   <th> city </th>
  </tr>
</table>
    <div id="check-emails">
      
    </div>
    <button id="clickme">
    Click me
    </button>
```

I want to store the email ids so that I could create another ajax request in the future with the variable, which contains those selected email id's of the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the way you concatenate the value of `response.data[i].user_email` in the string that represents the `tr` element is wrong.

Here's a snippet to illustrate the way you should concatenate strings in `JavaScript`

```js
$("#goBtn").on("click",function(){

  //assume I have the response data as follows:
  var response = {
    data:[
        {
          user_name: "zyx",
          user_email: "zyx.com",
          user_contact: "5555",
          state: "tn",
          city: "chennai",
          user_license: ""
        },
        {
          user_name: "abx",
          user_email: "abx.com",
          user_contact: "45555",
          state: "tn",
          city: "mumbai",
          user_license: ""
        }
      ]
  };

  for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
  
$("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> <input type='checkbox' value='" + response.data[i].user_email + "'>"+response.data[i].user_name+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_contact+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_license+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_email+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].state+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].city);
  }
});



//to process selected users: 
 $('#clickme').on('click', function(){
  var selected = $('input:checked');
   var emails = [];
   selected.each(function(){
    //alert(element);
    emails.push($(this).val());
   });
   
   $('#check-emails').html(emails);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="goBtn">Go</button>
<table id="table" border=1>
  <tr>
   <th> Name </th>
   <th> contact </th>
   <th> license </th>
   <th> email </th>
   <th> state </th>
   <th> city </th>
  </tr>
</table>
    <div id="check-emails">
      
    </div>
    <button id="clickme">
    Click me
    </button>
```

As an example, you have a variable named `str` containing a person's name and you want to put that name in string, here's how to do:

```js
var str = 'John Doe';
console.log('My name is ' + str + ', I\'m happy to be in StackOverflow !'); // output: My name is John Doe, I'm happy to be in StackOverflow !
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> <input type='checkbox' value = '"+response.data[i].user_email+"'>"+response.data[i].user_name+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_contact+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_license+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].user_email+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].state+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].city+"</td>");
```